# Problems while upgrading Linux VM

Tags: virtual-machine, kali-linux

Problem: After running "sudo apt upgrade" command on a Kali Virtual Machine, the upgrade gets stuck and web-pages stop loading, on both the VM and host machine. For webpages to start loading again I need to restart my machine.

Solutions that have tried: Reinstalling the VM(pre-built vm and clean image), changing the mirror servers, installing a VM on different virtualization program (VMWare and Virtualbox).

No packets are being lost, shouldn't be a network problem as I have a second machine with Ubuntu installed on it that I updated and upgraded without any problems.

[image]

Comment: have you looked at the official docs for this: https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/updating-kali/

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I have wasted anyone's time. I ran the upgrade again after a few days of not touching the system and it upgraded without any hiccups.
I am still not sure what was the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A very good way to solve this kind of problem in a Kali virtual machine is to run a complete cleanup and update.  I have done this successfully a couple of times on my own virtual machines.

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Then run sudo apt full-upgrade to renew packages and remove old ones.